# PayPal Smart Payment Buttons: Display only one payment method

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to display for example only giropay on the buttons?

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/#try-the-buttons

I would like to deactivate everything else.

Comment: The paypal smart buttons do not allow that option. It basically displays the available payment options to a user per their location. so depending on which country anyone is in, they may see different options. if you want that control, you may have to mail them or try other options than the smart buttons.